# how to make a class works for infinte in python selenium webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

i have a small script written with python selenuim webdriver:

```
class Mybot:
    def __init__(self):
        search = input("Enter URL Here : ")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome("")
        driver.get(search)
        time.sleep(5)
        search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
        search_box.clear()
        search_box.send_keys('Free Fire')
        search_box.submit()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('').click()
        time.sleep(5)
```

but it works for one time and stop, But i want it to work for infinite (or untill i stop it)
how exactly can i do that

Answer (score 0):

Just do while loop with true :

```
while(True):
    search = "https://www.google.com"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
    driver.get(search)
    time.sleep(5)
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    search_box.clear()
    search_box.send_keys('Free Fire', Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(5)
```

in case you wanna break, just put any if condition, and break from the loop.

Comment: it doesn't works, the program stops working at the last line

Comment: Cause the xpath is not defined

Comment: everthing works, but it does not repeat the same operations

Comment: This is strange, I am running the updated code above, and it is working in infinite loop.